# Downloading Google maps data points?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is it possible to download Google Maps data points?

It would be useful in order to gather all the restaurants in a dataset for example.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Mapperz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153234/download-google-maps-data-points/226880#comment225366_153234):

> Think you need to use the places api
>   https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro but needs to be
>   used with google maps.